# Calling a method form one class inside another class. Help me understand the logic

Tags: java, class, methods, hashmap

I created a simple program which prints the values on the screen using HashMap. 
Here is the part I don't understand. When I create a "Person" object inside the main class, and call the method "addPerson" using the Person's object, the program prints `Peter 10 points`.
However, when I try to call the method from another class (in my case "Help"), I get a result 
`Peter null points`.
Why "addPersonDifferentMethod" doesn't pass any parameters to the HashMap? Is there any way I can achieve something similar to what I am trying to do here? That means calling the method from one class inside another class?(Without using static)

Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person name = new Person();
    name.addPerson("Peter",10);
    System.out.println("Peter " + name.getMap().get("Peter") + " points");

    Person name2 = new Person();
    Help help = new Help();
    help.addPersonDifferentMethod();
    System.out.println("Peter " + name2.getMap().get("Peter") + " points");   
}
```

Class Person

```
public class Person {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public void addPerson(String name, int points){
        map.put(name, points); 
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getMap(){
        return this.map;
    }
}
```

Class Help

```
public class Help {
    Person name2 = new Person();

    public void addPersonDifferentMethod(){
        name2.addPerson("Peter", 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just because you call the `Person` in your main class, and the `Person` in your `Help` class both "name2", doesn't mean it's the same `Person`.

Comment: In other words, this "name2" `name2.getMap().get("Peter")` in `Main` is not the same as this "name2" `name2.addPerson("Peter", 10);` in `Help`

Comment: Because name and name2 are different objects.

Comment: And i think you should also read more about class modeling since `Person name = new Person(); name.addPerson("Peter",10);` looks really scary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addPersonDifferentMethod` method of `Help` class acts on a different `Person` object than the one you have defined in `main`. If you want to achieve similar result, you need to pass the reference of the `Person` object to `addPersonDifferentMethod` method, e.g. modify the `Help` class to:

```
class Help {

    public void addPersonDifferentMethod(Person name2){
        name2.addPerson("Peter", 10);
        name2.addPerson("Martin", 15);
    }
}
```

And, call the method from `main` with `Person` object that you have created:

```
Person name = new Person();
name.addPerson("Peter",10);
System.out.println("Peter " + name.getMap().get("Peter") + " points");

Person name2 = new Person();
Help help = new Help();
help.addPersonDifferentMethod(name2);
System.out.println("Peter " + name2.getMap().get("Peter") + " points");
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could pass object references aswell.